# Pattern associated to a named group

Tags: python, regex

The following code gives all the named groups used in a pattern.

```
import re

pattern = r"(?P<DEF_FUNC>def (?P<NAME_FUNC>\w+)\s*\((.*?)\):)|(?P<OTHERS>\w+)"
regex   = re.compile(pattern)

for name in sorted(
    regex.groupindex,
    key = regex.groupindex.get
):
    print(name)
```

Here is the corresponding output.

```
DEF_FUNC
NAME_FUNC
OTHERS
```

I would like to also have the corresponding patterns so as to obtain the following output.

```
DEF_FUNC  --> def (?P<NAME_FUNC>\w+)\s*\((.*?)\)
NAME_FUNC --> \w+
OTHERS    --> \w+
```

Is there a tricky way to do that without doing it "at hand" via regex searches in the pattern text ?

Comment: do you want to print the patterns along with the result? I so, I guess you'll have to copy paste your stuff… the problem being that DEF_FUNC is composed of NAME_FUNC and thus blocks way to "cheat"…

Comment: Hello. I want to know each pattern associated to a named group. In my question, the printing is just to see and test the results.

Comment: I'd love to be corrected by someone, but I'm pretty sure you'd need to write a function to do this: I do not see any built in functionality that achieves what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can check sre_parse:

```
import re, sre_parse
pattern = r"(?P<DEF_FUNC>def (?P<NAME_FUNC>\w+)\s*\((.*?)\):)|(?P<OTHERS>\w+)"
v = sre_parse.parse(pattern)
print v.pattern.groupdict   # sub-pattern id of each group
#print v.dump()
print v.data  # find the subgroups and match the ids
```

Comment: This looks very interesting ! This seems to give all the informations. I will play with that.

Comment: That's great this `v.dump()`. That will really help. Thanks a lot for pointing this.